# zip two collections based on predicate (Scala)

Tags: scala

I have two collections of the following:

```
case class Foo(id: String)
case class Bar(id: String, fooId: String)
```

I'd like to zip them, getting a collection of pairs, but where `Foo.id == Bar.fooId`. Basically join on a foreign key predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every `Bar` has an associated `Foo` and you have the same number of each and the IDs are all different, and you don't mind O(n log n) runtime, you can

```
foos.sortBy(_.id) zip bars.sortBy(_.fooId)
```

to get a collection of `(Foo, Bar)` pairs.

Otherwise, just make a map from IDs to `Foo`s (assuming they have unique IDs) and look it up.  E.g.

```
val foomap = foos.map(x => x.id -> x).toMap
bars.map(y => foomap(y.fooId) -> y)
```

If you might have multiple IDs or whatnot and need to do some error handling, consider using `groupBy` to make the map from IDs, and then check the length of the values (succeeding if you have one, and doing appropriate error checking if not):

```
val foomap = foos.groupBy(_.id).mapValues{
  case vs if vs.length == 1 => vs.head
  case _ => throw new Exception("Duplicate IDs")
}
```

(Pro tip: `mapValues` is lazy, so you'll only get the exception if `bars` actually needs to look up a key that has duplicates.)

Comment: Yup, already went down this path, I just thought there may be some magic collection API that helps me here. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a magical do-everything-super-fast API, but `sortBy` and `groupBy` each do some heavy lifting depending on your use case.